# Reversible Functions

Tags: design, design-patterns, json

Currently writing a JSON Importer and creating some POJOs based on the data. I also have a requirement to write an JSON Exporter which take the information in the POJOs and exports a JSON doc.

To me I would like to reuse the the same code if possible. Does such a thing exist where you can reverse the function/method? i.e I could (depending on what I pass it) process it in the correct order and output the desired result, using the same code?

Thanks

Comment: Is your question/problem generally about "reversing a function"? or is it specifically about your JSON issue?    If it's specifically about serialising JSON then consider a library such as Gson - https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md

Comment: @BenCottrell Keep in mind that library/tool recommendations are off-topic, so even if that was the OP's intent then we'd have to close the question instead of answering the on-topic part.

Comment: I think I as well as maybe others are confused - it sounds as though you wish to create a method that can take a Java object and give you a JSON String, or take a JSON String and give you an Object - but by reverse you mean avoid writing a serializer and deserializer separately? It may be possible - I can't personally think of a way but I'd certainly advise against it - as well as advise against not using GSON or something similar.

Comment: No it's about "reversing a function", I mentioned the JSON just to put things into context

Comment: @Ixrec I believe it needs clarifying - the question about reversible functions, while definitely a good/interesting question for the site, may just be a seriously over-complex solution to a very easy/simple problem.

Comment: @NUIG2014 fair enough then, disregard the JSon suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible.

- [*Invertible syntax descriptions: Unifying parsing and pretty printing* by Tillmann Rendel and Klaus Ostermann](http://www.informatik.uni-marburg.de/~rendel/unparse/) is one fairly well-known approach for parsing/unparsing (which is kind of what you are doing) based on partial isomorphisms.

The paper also points to other approaches based on

- Arrows ([*Polytypic compact printing and parsing* by Patrik Jansson and Johan Jeuring](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~patrikj/poly/dc/)),
- BiArrows ([*There and back again: arrows for invertible programming* by Artem Alimarine, Sjaak Smetsers, Arjen van Weelden, Marko van Eekelen, and Rinus Plasmeijer](http://ftp.cs.kun.nl/Clean/papers/2005/alia2005-biarrowsHaskellWorkshop.pdf), note that this is about invertible programming in general, not just parsing/unparsing or serialization/deserialization), and
- [*An injective language for reversible computation* by Shin-Cheng Mu, Zhenjiang Hu, and Masato Takeichi](http://takeichi.ipl-lab.org/~scm/pub/reversible.pdf), a full calculus for reversible programming in general.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three major reasons why it is generally not possible to programmatically invert an arbitrary function in most general programming languages:

1. Only a one-to-one function (aka a "bijection") can be inverted even in principle. That means the function must produce a unique output value for every single possible combination of inputs. In practice most functions are not one-to-one, nor would it make any sense for them to be. For instance, a correct JSON parsing function will produce the same POJO for many different strings.
2. The function would have to be composed entirely of operations/functions that have known inverses. Even the basic arithmetic operations are not quite invertible (due to overflow, underflow, rounding errors and the division by zero problem), and as far as I know the built-in methods of most languages are largely non-invertible (concatenating strings, accessing array elements, taking substrings, etc are all not one-to-one).
3. It doesn't make sense to talk about inverting a function which has side effects. What is the opposite of sending data over a network connection, saving data to a hard drive or printing a character to a screen? In some contexts these operations may be undoable, but you can't un-print a character before any characters have been printed, whereas you can decrement an integer without incrementing it first.

However, it is theoretically possible to design a language (or a DSL within your favorite language) that consists solely of strictly invertable operations, in which it would be possible to programmatically invert any function. The links in Jörg's answer cover this far better than I can.

For the purposes of your JSON importer/exporter, it's likely that simply writing two separate code paths would be a lot less work than constructing an invertable DSL with all the string building and object constructing operations needed to do what you want.

Comment: Your first point is technically correct but useless. While the strings `{"a":1,"b":2}` and `{ "b": 2, "\u0061": 1 }` aren't string-equal, they are equal in the sense that they JSON-encode the same data structure. With an equality relation `json_equals(a, b)` and functions `encode(obj)`, `decode(json)`, we'd need `json_equals(json, encode(decode(json)))` to hold for all JSON documents that can be generated by `encode(…)`, and `deep_equals(obj, decode(encode(obj)))` for all objects that can be encoded. Or phrased differently: we are dealing large equivalence classes, making bijection feasible.